# Accessing photos on iPhone iCloud backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos

Is it possible to access photos from iPhone iCloud backups without loading them onto a iPhone?

After losing my phone, I purchased a new iPhone with less memory. I was able to partially restore my apps and photos on to this new iPhone but not completely due to lack of space.

Now I have a situation where several hundred photos are stored in a iPhone backup but I have seemingly no way of accessing them without purchasing a iPhone with the same memory as the previous one.

Is there any way around this?

(I have looked into a few of the third party tools like 'iMobie phoneRescue' or Dr Fone and if anyone has any first hand experience using these I would be interested to hear from you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a copy of the backup, there are a couple of ways to get these back.

1. Free
   http://www.itunesextractor.com/extract-photos-from-iphone-backup.html
2. Paid
   https://www.imobie.com/phonerescue/

I would make a backup of your file, then try the free one first and if that doesn't work try the paid version if these photos are important.

Hope one of these will work!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iCloud Photo Library, you can access your photos through icloud.com or the Photos app on your Mac (if any).